# How to fix OGG-01163 in oracle goldenGate

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

Have an error in my *.rpt file:

```
2019-09-26 17:58:56  ERROR   OGG-01163  Bad column length (56) specified for column AUTHORISATION_ID in table TCPF.OPERATION, maximum allowable length is 40
```

When the extract started the colum length was 40. Then it was extended to 200. DDLs are not replicated. Replicat is created with Java handler with no target DB and so this length mismatch makes no problem.

The replicat stopped abended at this record and won't budge. The following option in the RPT file didn't help:

```
reperror 01163, ignore
```

as this is for only Oracle DB errors.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Solution. Generate source definition file on the source DB:

```
$ ./defgen paramfile dirprm/myschema.prm
```

myschema.prm

```
CHARSET UTF-8
DEFSFILE dirprm/myschema.def purge CHARSET UTF-8 FORMAT RELEASE 12.3
userid ***, password ***
NOCATALOG
table MYSCHEMA.*;
```

Copy the def-file to the target server and in the replicat PRM-file add the line:

```
SOURCEDEFS dirprm/myschema.def OVERRIDE
```

Note that OVERRIDE option is necessary. Otherwise metadata from the trail-file will be used.

Start the replicat, it must work now. After all pending data is replicated restart the EXTRACT on the source DB. After that the SOURCEDEFS parameter may be removed from the REPLICAT PRM-file. Dont forget to restart the REPLICAT process.